# Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express: Can debug but not build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

When I debug my C# program <kbd>F5</kbd>, my program will run as intended; however, upon building it <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, my program immediately shuts down: "(Program) has stopped working". What are some possible explanations for this?

Comment: your program shuts down or visual studio shuts down?

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to guess at this and write the code to tell you.  Add an event handler for AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException and display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+F5 is usually not the shortcut for building, but for starting the program without the debugger attached.

I would guess that your program is then started with a different working folder and crashes because you somewhere try to access a file relative to the working folder that is not found when you start with Ctrl+F5.